# Hide tab markers in Ace editor

Tags: tabs, editor, markers, ace-editor

Ace editor shows tab markers.  Tabs are marked by dots.  Is there a way to hide them?

Here is the code I'm using to load the editor:

```
var themeCssAceEditor = ace.edit("themeCssAceEditor");
baseCssAceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
themeCssAceEditor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/css");
themeCssAceEditor.on("change", function test() { });
```

Also, can anyone explain the meaning of the following line?                  `themeCssAceEditor.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`themeCssAceEditor.setDisplayIndentGuides(false)` (see kitchen-sink demo)

`useSoftTabs` means tabs are expanded to spaces